# Separating actions from patterns

Tags: awk

Consider:

```
$ echo line1 | awk '1END{ print "line2"}'
line1
line2
```

Note the lack of space between `1` and `END`.  Is this standard, or a quirk of my implementation of awk?  What is the grammar rule for separating an action from the following address?

Comment: What platform and what version of AWK? I get a syntax error from `gawk`, `nawk` and `mawk` on Linux.

Comment: That was awk on OSX.  (From memory: awk -v printed something like `awk version 2007....` Perhaps I'll update the comment when I have access to the machine later today.)

Comment: Without any space, gawk 3.1.3 does not give a syntax error but only executes the `END` block.  With a space, it does give a syntax error.

Comment: Inserting a semicolon after the 1 works for me using `gawk` 3.1.6 and 3.1.7. On those versions, space or no space gives me a syntax error.

Comment: The version exhibiting this behavior is awk version 20070501 on BSD (OS X)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using an old version of `awk`. In the original `awk` language it wasn't necessary to separate rules on the same line with a semicolon. It was added for consistency with the treatment of statements within an action.

I found this:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Statements_002fLines.html

This works for me using GNU Awk 4.0.1:

```
$ echo line1 | awk '1; END { print "line2" }'
line1
line2
```

If I remove the `;` I get a syntax error. HTH